# Get the Gatsby Link destination and conditionally render exit animation with Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, use-context, framer-motion

I've built a small website to learn more about page transition with Gatsby and Framer Motion and Styled Components.

*[SPOILER]: My problem to be solved is at the end of the code blocks*

The way it's currently working is simple:

An **homepage** with a list of projects

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Welcome />
      <WorkList />
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

A **project page template** that generate each project thanks to `createPages` (here is a simplified version)

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

// Components
...

// Data
import Projects from "../data/works.json"

// Styles
...

// Variants
...

const Project = ({ pageContext }) => {
  const project = Projects.find(({ id }) => id === pageContext.id)
  
  // lots of functions here

  return (
    <Layout>
      <ProjectWrapper>
        <Container>
          <ProjectContent>
            <BackgroundLines />
            <ProjectContentInner>
              <ProjectHeader>
                <!-- here the header logic -->
              </ProjectHeader>
              <ProjectBlocks>
                <!-- here the content logic -->
              </ProjectBlocks>
            </ProjectContentInner>
            <ProjectFooter>
              <!-- here the footer logic -->
            </ProjectFooter>
          </ProjectContent>
        </Container>
      </ProjectWrapper>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Project
```

The **Layout component** is holding the navigation

```
// Components
import Header from "./header"

// Styles
import { GlobalStyle } from "../styles/globalStyles"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Header />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

and last but not least, the `gatsby.browser.js` wrapped with the `AnimatePresence` and the `Context Provider`

```
import React from "react"
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion"
import { LocationProvider } from "./src/context/locationContext"

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => (
  <LocationProvider>
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>{element}</AnimatePresence>
  </LocationProvider>
)

export const shouldUpdateScroll = () => {
  return false
}
```

So what I want to do seemed easy but it turned out that is not (at least for me).
I've currently made a beautiful transition between 2 projects, similar to the one you could see [in here](https://www.pentagram.com/work/orbikular?rel=sector&rel-id=5).

If you scroll to the bottom of the page, you can see that the next project's header is shown as a preview and once you click on it, it will smoothly transition to the next project page.

Awesome.

BUT, but this transition is a problem when the user clicks on the link in the navigation that takes him to the home or to another page.

I don't want to have the same exit transition, where some elements disappear while others overlaps, and I don't want the same timing. I want to do something completely different, based on where I'm headed to.

What I thought of as a solution, is to conditionally render `exit transition` in framer motion, to have different exit animation based on some variables.

**I want to be able to track the `Link Destination` before the component unmount in order to be able to conditionally render an exit transion in Framer Motion**

Since, as you may have seen, the navigation isn't inside the `project.js` I tried with `createContext` and `useContext`, getting the `location.pathname` to have an `origin` state and a `e.target.pathname` on `Link` to have a `destination` state. This doesn't actually works because everything seems to get a rerender.

I just provided the pieces of codes that seemed crucial to understand the overall structure, but I can go deeper with the way I've built `variants` or the current `exit` animations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help but you can get the `props` as any React component in the `wrapPageElement`:

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  console.log("props", props)
  if(props.location.pathname==='/'){
    //return some other animation stuff
  }

  return <LocationProvider {...props}>
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>{element}</AnimatePresence>
  </LocationProvider>
}
```

Comment: I knew this but actually, I would need the destination more than the origin of the page, since I want to change the behaviour based on where I'm headed to.

E.g. if I'm on the project, and I'm going to the home, make this transition. Otherwise, make this other transition.

Comment: I lack of the context of your implementation but you can get both data (origin and target) from many Gatsby Browser API (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onRouteUpdate) for example. There, you can try to set some logic based on the destination

Comment: I think that onRouteUpdate could be a good starting point. Thanks! than I should figure out how to pass this information before the component unmount to be able to set the conditional exit animation.